# Чем отличается ложь от вранья?

Tags: значение-слов, семантика

В чём семантическое различие форм слов от "лгать" и "врать"? Слова вроде похожи, почти идентичны по смыслу, но различие всё равно ощущается.

Вот, например, нельзя *обоврать*, но можно *оболгать*. При этом можно *завраться*, но *залгаться* уже не получится.

В чём же отличие этих слов?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

В современном значении различаются только стилистически: ложь - нейтральное, враньё-разговорное (не лги - не ври), но когда-то действительно различались: ложь - сознательно искажённая истина, клевета; враньё - чепуха, пустая болтовня, нелепость, вздор, сплетни. Клевета и сплетни уже серьёзно отличаются как бы степенью искажения истины и степенью осознанности. Ложь - серьёзный порок, враньё - неприятная черта.

Answer (score 9):

Итак, враньё и ложь — разные вещи. Ложь — не просто преднамеренно неправильное высказывание, она происходит от причины и ведёт к цели. А враньё не имеет ни причины, ни цели, и в большинстве случаев приносит только позор.

Answer (score 6):

А мне кажется, что слово "врать" чаще можно услышать в разговорной речи. Редко мать, которая ругает сына за то, что он скрыл полученную в школе двойку, скажет ему: "Не лги мне!" А вот "не ври" — скорее всего. "Ложь" — это более "высокий штиль", как мне кажется)))

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то эти слова можно считать синонимами, но каждый для себя может представить их смыслы по-разному, ничего криминального в этом нет.
Например, для меня ложь — это намеренное искажение истины, а вранье — пустые фантазии.

Comment: Да вот, кстати, может быть кто-то обоснует разницу между словами "обворовать" и "обокрасть"?

Answer (score 3):

Враньё - это искажение формализуемой информации, ложь - скорее неверная интерпретация реальных фактов.

Answer (score 2):

Лгать — преднамеренно искажать информацию. Ложь — это задача одного одного человека опорочить другого. Задуманная подлость.

Враньё — это вымыслы человека, в его задачу не входит оклеветать другого человека или испортить ему жизнь. Это словесное жульничество, например продавца, который хочет продать вам или дорогой, или не пользующийся спросом товар. Для этого продавец использует приемы вранья, то есть наделяет товар такими  характеристиками, которых в товаре нет, но человек  верит словам продавца и покупает. 
Враньё используется в тех случаях, когда человек хочет поднять свою значимость, наделить себя лучшими чертами, представить себя в глазах окружающих лучше, чем есть на самом деле. В России говорят: "Не хочешь - не слушай, а врать не мешай."

Answer (score 1):

Разница между ложью и враньём схожа с разницей слов "жадность" и "алчность".
*Жадность - это нежелание отдавать своё, а алчность – желание поиметь чужое*.

Ложью преследуется цель, в основе которой лежит корысть, желание получить от кого-то материальное или эмоциональное благо, причём - безвозмездно и незаслуженно. В то время как враньё используется для ухода от обязательств или ответственности, выгораживания себя, либо для искусственного увеличения собственной значимости.

Как видим, принципиальное отличие вранья от лжи – в векторе ориентации обмана. Если вектор обращён на себя любимого и не несёт вреда от субъекта объекту, то это – враньё. Если же вектор обращён к объекту и преследует цель несанкционированного отъёма благ (средств, ресурсов, времени, эмоций и т.д.), то это – ложь.

Answer (score 1):

Заметьте: "Врёте!", "враль!", - так с эмоциями говорят положительные, чистые, прямые персонажи (например, в кино: директор завода Калугина в "Служебном романе") в простых, не криминальных ситуациях ("Врёшь!" - в более острых). Врёт - это эмоциональное обличение, созвучно c "вор", "ворует".

"Ложь!", "лжёте" - произносят отрицательные герои типа Каренина, Мерзляева, Самохвалова, Аникеевой (члена правления в фильме "Гараж"), всегда связано с прямым юридическим или моральным обвинением в проступке, нарушении или с попытками оправдаться в таких негативных поступках, действиях. Созвучно с "лижет", "подлиза", "ляжет".

Comment: «Мымра», как зовут её за глаза несколько десятков подчиненных, возглавляет крупное статистическое учреждение. (http://fandea.ru/876-lyudmila-prokofevna-kalugina-mymra-iz-filma-sluzhebnyi-roman.html). Герои типа Каренина — отрицательные? Ой как спорно.

Answer (score 1):

Оба понятия являются показателями выдумки (вымысла) и несостоятельности. "Враньё" заключает в себе невозможность, небывальщину. "Ложь" заключает в себе возможность выдаваемого проявления.  
Возможное и невозможное. 
Выдуманное и невозможное – враньё. Выдуманное и такое вполне возможно, но всё-таки не состоялось (не состоится) – ложь. 
Примеры для того, чтобы было понятно, что слово "ложь" не путается со словом "враньё": 
Ложный след - есть след, но он не тот, который необходим. 
Перевирать, перевранный - 1) данные искажены до того, что походят на небылицы; 2) изобретательность некоторых исказителей, настолько красочна, что превосходит первоисточник.

Answer (score -3):

Лгать и врать - синонимы.Просто врать - более грубое слово.

Comment: В 5-м ответе от 18 июн '13 в 6:48 — такой же смысл, так зачем повторять сказанное. Для справки: после точек принято давать пробел, на месте тире — тире (Alt+151).